# R - Create new variable based on certain conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame `df` with longitudinal data in long format (see below). I would like to create a new variable called `new.var` based on some conditions. This new variable should be 1, if the first value of postLin for a person is > 0 but <= 1 or if the the value of postLin == 0 **and** the value of preLin == 0. **There can only be a maximum of one 1 on `new.var` per person (`ID`).**

```
df <- read.table(text=
"ID       preLin   postLin      
800057    -8.55    0               
800057    -6.34    0           
800057    -5.34    0           
800057    -4.34    0         
800057        0    0.33   
800119    -0.88    0  
800119        0    0           
800119        0    1       
834011     -4.1    0 
834011     -3.1    0   
834341        0    1.34 
834341        0    2.34   
834341        0    3.34   
834341        0    5.34    
834341        0    6.66  
800125        0    0
800125        0    2.14
897177    -0.33    0 
897177        0    0.67 
897177        0    1.67", header=TRUE)
```

First, I tried this code:

```
df$new.var1 <- ifelse(df$preLin == 0 & (df$postLin >= 0 & df$postLin <= 1), 1, 0)
```

However, for ID 800119 there will then be two 1s.

My expected outcome would look like this:

```
df_new <- read.table(text=
"ID       preLin   postLin    new.var  
800057    -8.55    0          0         
800057    -6.34    0          0  
800057    -5.34    0          0
800057    -4.34    0          0     
800057        0    0.33       1 
800119    -0.88    0          0 
800119        0    0          1  
800119        0    1          0
834011     -4.1    0          0 
834011     -3.1    0          0 
834341        0    1.34       0
834341        0    2.34       0
834341        0    3.34       0  
834341        0    5.34       0    
834341        0    6.66       0
800125        0    0          1
800125        0    2.14       0
897177    -0.33    0          0
897177        0    0.67       1
897177        0    1.67       0", header=TRUE)
```

Does anyone know a solution for my issue? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: But you *should* get a 1 for `new.var` for that 3rd instance of 800119. That's the correct value for that row because `preLin` is 0 and `postLin` is both >= 0 and <= 1.

Comment: There should be a 1 for new.var only for the first time when my conditions were met. Consequently, only the 2nd instance of 800119 should get a 1 but not the 3rd instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expected outcome comes from declaring the condition in `ifelse` as follows:

```
df$new.var1 <- ifelse((df$postLin > 0 & df$postLin < 1) | (df$preLin == 0 & df$postLin ==0), 1, 0)
```

*value = 1* if df$postLin gets values between 0 and 1 (but not 0 and 1) **or** if both df$preLin and df$postLin are 0. Otherwise *value = 0*

Result:

```
       ID preLin postLin new.var1
1  800057  -8.55    0.00        0
2  800057  -6.34    0.00        0
3  800057  -5.34    0.00        0
4  800057  -4.34    0.00        0
5  800057   0.00    0.33        1
6  800119  -0.88    0.00        0
7  800119   0.00    0.00        1
8  800119   0.00    1.00        0
9  834011  -4.10    0.00        0
10 834011  -3.10    0.00        0
11 834341   0.00    1.34        0
12 834341   0.00    2.34        0
13 834341   0.00    3.34        0
14 834341   0.00    5.34        0
15 834341   0.00    6.66        0
16 800125   0.00    0.00        1
17 800125   0.00    2.14        0
18 897177  -0.33    0.00        0
19 897177   0.00    0.67        1
20 897177   0.00    1.67        0
```

**Remark**: keeping the condition as *<=1* will result in an additional one in the third 800119, as @shirewoman2 said in her comment

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach which uses `tidyverse`. It groups your ID`s and uses the filter you want. A little helper columns is build which finds the first occurence in postLin, it is removed later.` mutate`with`ifelse `applies your rules. Then the result is joined with the original DF and NA`s are turned into zeros.

```r
library(tidyverse)


df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  dplyr::filter(postLin > 0 | (postLin == 0 & preLin == 0)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    first = dplyr::first(postLin)
  ) %>%
  mutate(new.var = ifelse((postLin == first & postLin < 1), 1, 0)) %>%
  select(-c(first)) %>%
  right_join(df, by = c("ID", "preLin", "postLin")) %>%
  mutate(new.var = ifelse(is.na(new.var), 0, new.var)) %>%
  arrange(ID, preLin, postLin)
#> # A tibble: 20 x 4
#> # Groups:   ID [6]
#>        ID preLin postLin new.var
#>     <int>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 800057  -8.55    0          0
#>  2 800057  -6.34    0          0
#>  3 800057  -5.34    0          0
#>  4 800057  -4.34    0          0
#>  5 800057   0       0.33       1
#>  6 800119  -0.88    0          0
#>  7 800119   0       0          1
#>  8 800119   0       1          0
#>  9 800125   0       0          1
#> 10 800125   0       2.14       0
#> 11 834011  -4.1     0          0
#> 12 834011  -3.1     0          0
#> 13 834341   0       1.34       0
#> 14 834341   0       2.34       0
#> 15 834341   0       3.34       0
#> 16 834341   0       5.34       0
#> 17 834341   0       6.66       0
#> 18 897177  -0.33    0          0
#> 19 897177   0       0.67       1
#> 20 897177   0       1.67       0
```